# Carriage return and new line with Java and readLine()

Tags: java

I am using the following code to establish a HTTP connection and read data:

```
con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json").openConnection();
...
con.connect();
while (line = rd.readLine()) {
    if (line.contains("\r\n")) {
      System.out.println("Carriage return + new line");
    }
}
```

However, it seems like "\r\n" is not part of the string (`line`), although the server does return them. How can I read the data and detect "\r\n"?

Thanks,

Joel

Comment: `while (line = rd.readLine())` won't even compile. Also, what's the type of `rd` and how do you get hold of it?

Comment: I assume you are using `BufferedReader` with `rd`, when you read with `readLine()`, `\n` and `\r` chars will be trimmed from the result, you can not see them if you use this method. You should consider using `read()`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If `rd` is of type `BufferedReader` there is no way to figure out if `readLine()` returned something that ended with `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n`... the end-of-line characters are discarded and not part of the returned string.

If you really care about these characters, you can't go through `readLine()`. You'll have to for instance read the characters one by one through [`read()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29).

Comment: I don't like questions / comments starting with "he should not care about that"... he could for instance be sitting with a test-specification that says "look for \r\n uses". It's unlikely, but the point is this: *you don't know*!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using BufferedReader. Just use character-based methods instead of readLine().

Comment: I suppose you meant `readLine` instead of `getLine` (only found in javax.sound.* for Java SE)

Answer (score 12):

From the [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29):

```
public String readLine() throws IOException
```

> Read a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.
>   Returns:
>   A String containing the contents of the line, **not including any line-termination characters**, or null if the end of the stream has been reached
>   Throws:
>   IOException - If an I/O error occurs

Comment: But that doesn't solve the issue, how do you get the line terminating characters in the string?

Comment: @JaredBeekman JDK docs are good, but does not include everything.
For example from this description it is not clear whether last empty line (as often seen in text editor) is returned as empty string or not considered a line at all.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, **`readLine()`** uses `\n` and `\r` as line feed and carriage return end characters to determine the next lines. So, when you use `readLine()`, then you won't get `\n` or `\r` characters to be displayed in the console as these characters will be masked by the `readLine()`. For more information about `readLine()`, refer to the official [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

To avoid such behavior, we should use **`read()`** method from `BufferedReader` package. The following sample snippet will help to understand how these `\n` and `\r` are getting recognized using `read()`.

Let's say you have a file called **test_lineFeed.txt** which contains line breaks, and if you want to replace them with some defined format like "CR-LF" (CR --> Carriage return, LF --> Line Feed), then use the following snippet.

```
BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream("/home/test_lineFeed.txt")
            ));

    int s1 = 0;
    String formattedString = "";
    while ((s1 = reader1.read()) != -1) {

        char character = (char) s1;

        System.out.println("Each Character: "+character+" its hexacode(Ascii): "+Integer.toHexString(character));
        //output : "0a" --> \n 
        //output : "0d" --> \r

        if (character == '\n'){
            formattedString+=" <LF> ";
        }else if (character =='\r'){
            formattedString+=" <CR> ";
        }else
            formattedString+=character;

    }
    System.out.println(formattedString);
```

Comment: Won't you get an `incomparable types: char and String` error if you compare `character` variable  which  is `char` with `'\n'` or `'\r'`?

Comment: char character = (char) s1;
This is where the type casting is happening. I do not see incomparable types error because of this.