# Read text file and split each newline into a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, readline

So basically I'm reading a text file that has a bunch of lines. I need to extract certain lines from the text file and add those specific lines into string array. I've been trying to split each newLine with: "\n" , "\r". This did not work. I keep getting this error as well:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at A19010.main(A19010.java:47)

Here is the code:

```
Path objPath = Paths.get("dirsize.txt");
    if (Files.exists(objPath)){

     File objFile = objPath.toFile();
     try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                             new FileReader(objFile))){
          String line = in.readLine();

           while(line != null){

            String[] linesFile = line.split("\n");
            String line0 = linesFile[0];
            String line1 = linesFile[1];
            String line2 = linesFile[2];



            System.out.println(line0 + "" + line1);
            line = in.readLine();
           }

        }
         catch(IOException e){

             System.out.println(e);
         }

    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println(
              objPath.toAbsolutePath() + " doesn't exist");
    }
```

Comment: Where are you splitting the line..?

Comment: I had this before:  String[] linesFile = line.split("\n");

Comment: After you have done the BufferedReader.readLine() you have read the line. What are you then trying to do? Split it into words?

Comment: I want to split each newline of text in the file and add it to a string array so I can latter extract certain parts from the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] linesFile = new String[] {line}; // this array is initialized with a single element
String line0 = linesFile[0]; // fine
String line1 = linesFile[1]; // not fine, the array has size 1, so no element at second index
String line2 = linesFile[2];
```

You're creating a `String[] linesFile` with one element, `line`, but then trying to access elements at index 1 and 2. This will give you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

You're not actually splitting anything here. `in.readLine();`, as the method says, reads a full line from the file.

**Edit:** You can add lines (Strings) dynamically to a list instead of an array, since you don't know the size.

```
List<String> lines = new LinkedList<String>(); // create a new list
String line = in.readLine(); // read a line at a time
while(line != null){ // loop till you have no more lines
    lines.add(line) // add the line to your list
    line = in.readLine(); // try to read another line
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand now why I get the error. So what would be the best way to split or add each line of the text file to a string array?

Comment: @oxxi Since you are reading each line, just add the `line` you read, to the array. However, since you don't know how many lines you might have, it might be better to use a `LinkedList<String>` to add the lines to. Take a look at the edit.

Comment: ok `LinkedList<>` worked for me. I was able to implement and access the text in the lines I wanted. Just though it would work with a normal string array. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @oxxi The problem with a String array (or any array for that matter) is that once you've initialized it, you can't resize it. If you realize you need more space, you have to create a new and bigger array, copy over all the elements and use the new one.

Answer (score 3):

`readLine()` method reads a entire line from the input but **removes the newLine characters** from it. When you split the line on `\n` character, you will not find one in the String. Hence, you get the exception.

Please, refer the answer in this [link for more clarity.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758525/carriage-return-and-new-line-with-java-and-readline)

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your String array with 1 element, namely line. linesFile[0] is therefore line and the rest of your array is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] linesFile = line.split("SPLIT-CHAR-HERE");
if(linesFile.length >= 3)
{
            String line0 = linesFile[0];
            String line1 = linesFile[1];
            String line2 = linesFile[2];
// further logic here
}else
{
//handle invalid lines here
}
```

Comment: could the "SPLIT-CHAR-HERE" be "\n". I'm on a mac by the way so would it be "\r"?

Answer (score 0):

You are using array to store the strings. Instead  use `ArrayList` from Java as ArrayList are dynamically growing. after your reading operation completes convert it into array.

```
    String line = in.readLine();
      ArrayList<String> str_list = new ArrayList<String>();
      String[] strArr = new String[str_list.size()];

           while(line != null){
             str_list.add(line);  
             line = in.readLine();
           }
    // at the end of the operation convert Arraylist to array
return   str_list.toArray(strArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are creating a new `String` array every time your parser reads in a new line. You then populate only the very first element in that `String` array with the `line` that is being read in with:

```
String[] linesFile = new String[] {line};
```

Since you create a new `String[]` with one element every single time your `while` loop runs from the top, you lose the values it stored from the previous iteration.

The solution is to use `new String[];` right before you enter the while loop. If you don't know how to use `ArrayList`, then I suggest a while loop like this:

```
int numberOfLine = 0;
while (in.readLine() != null)
{
    numberOfLine++;
}
String linesFile = new String[numberOfLine];
```

This will let you avoid using a dynamically resized `ArrayList` because you know how many lines your file contains from the above while loop. Then you would keep an additional counter (or resuse `numberOfLine` since we have no use for it anymore) so that you can populate this array:

```
numberOfLine = 0;
in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(objFile)); // reset the buffer
while ((String line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    linesFile[numberOfLine] = line;
    numberOfLine++;
}
```

At this point `linesFile` should be correctly populated with the lines in your file, such that `linesFile[i]` can be used to access the i'th line in the file.

Comment: So, I'm going to need 2 while loops?

Comment: The first `while` loop is purely to count the number of lines in the file. If you know this beforehand, then it isn't necessary. Additionally, you can avoid the first `while` loop by using an `ArrayList<String>` instead of `String[]`, but the trade-off is that this requires more memory.

Comment: I can see how it could work, but I couldn't figure out how to implement your code correctly with mine.