# How to skip carriage return as line breaker while reading a file in java

Tags: java

I am reading a text file using `BufferedReader.readLine()` in java. My text file was created with hidden line breaks. My question is I need to skip carriage return (`\r`) as line break, only need to consider line feed (`\n`) as line breaker.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what is a "hidden linebreak"? who created this broken file? can you ask her to fix the line break handling?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Carriage return and new line with Java and readLine()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758525/carriage-return-and-new-line-with-java-and-readline)

Answer (score 4):

You have to write your own `readLine`. `BufferedReader.readLine` will consider all \r, \n and \r\n as line breaks and you cannot change it. Make a helper where you define your own line breaks.

Edit:
could look like this

```
String readLineIgnoreCR(BufferedReader reader)
{
    int c = reader.read();
    String line = "";
    while(c >= 0)
    {
        if((char) c == '\r')
            continue;
        else if((char) c == '\n')
            return line;
        line += (char) c;

    }
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Well, I dont have enough reputation to comment yet. You answer wont work as the line should never have \r in it. According to documentation it will consider every \r to terminate a line https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

Comment: you should've used `StringBuilder`, otherwise your code would be awfully slow for big strings.

Comment: Also, it loops indefinitely because `c = reader.read()` is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Is correct:

```
    String readLineIgnoreCR(BufferedReader reader) {
        int c = 0;
        String line = "";
        while(c >= 0) {
            c = reader.read();
            if((char) c == '\r')
                continue;
            else if((char) c == '\n')
                return line;
            line += (char) c;
        }
        return line;
    }
```